# Failed to find DC operating point for AC analysis LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, spice, instrumentation-amplifier

I finally successfully added the MCP 606 (MCP 609) in LTspiceXVII. I am now facing an error "Failed to find DC operating point for AC analysis". I have checked the maximum supply of MCP 606 and turned the voltage supply down to +2.5V and -2.5V and DC voltage to 1V. Does anyone know what caused the error?

I switched the positive and negative inputs but still got the error. I realized this problem has also shown my lack of understanding of amplifiers. I would like to learn more. If anyone knows, could you please explain further why not possible in practice with the circuit in the first image?

[MC609](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/MCP609-I-ST?qs=R9WqqQqCiv74JTv7wEXyLQ%3D%3D)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your search, have you checked this: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html? It has not changed in the most recent version.

Comment: @devnull Thankyou. I am now facing an error "Failed to find DC operating point for AC analysis". I have checked the maximum supply of MCP 606 and turned the voltage supply down to +2.5V and -2.5V and DC voltage to 1V. Could anyone know what caused the error?

Comment: @tobalt Make that an answer (with both issues). If you could also add a warm recommendation to use the opamp symbol(s) already existent in `[Opamps]` instead of the lazy auto-generated ones, that would be great.

Comment: You have a circuit with positive dc feedback. Hence, a stable dc bias point is not possible.

Comment: @LvW I do not quite understand it. Could you explain it further? I am trying to improve my understanding of amplifiers. I switched the positive and negative input but still got that error.

Comment: I am afraid that your power supply connection is wrong. I assume that in LTSpice Vo is signal output. You have connected it with VEE.

Comment: Apologies, I must be working too much. Can't believe I made that silly mistake. Thank you, @LvW .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the apparent topology of the circuit drawn around the opamp, I guess you are trying to make an inverting amplifier. If so, it looks like you simply connected wires wrong. The input terminals would be swapped and output would be swapped with V-. With this present connection, the operation point would be far from usual (probably saturated somewhere with nonequilibrated inputs).

But in general, many manufacturer IC models are somewhat messy and upsetting to LTspice's solver. If you do not rely on some rather specific behavior of a certain op amp model, you should always attempt using a generic op amp model of LTspice (e.g. UniversalOpamp2 in the [Opamps] component folder) to reproduce simple behaviour. The UniversalOpamp can also be used to replace comparator models in many cases, when using high values for GBW product and slew rate. I mention the comparator replacement, if you were indeed trying to build some kind of circuit with positive feedback.

If you need more specific op amp behavior modelling, I would first suggest using the models already included in the [Opamps] folder before turning to other manufacturer models. This is because these included models are parts from Analog or Linear Tech which were probably tested to work well with LTspice (which is a software from Linear Tech).

Answer (score 4):

May I direct your attention to the second graph (updated version, simulation with positive feedback).

I don`t know if you are surprised about the results - because in reality such a circuit cannot and will not work (no correct bias point).
However, the ac analysis always assumes (a) a power supply which does exist since ever (no switch-on transients) and (b) no noise or any other external disturbaces.

Therefore, the program is able to find a suitable bias point. And the program did not make any error. You even can find such a bias point by simple pencil-and-paper calculation (ignoring your background knowledge about stability).

A mechanical analogy would be a small ball riding upon a larger one. This could be possible (in theory only) without any external disturbances.

But a TRAN analysis with power supplies switched on at t=0 would reveal this instability. But you also can see that something went wrong in your ac analysis. Look at the phase response which has a positive slope (rising phase) while the gain magnitude has a negative slope.

THIS violates the gain-phase relationship formulated by W. Bode !

Answer (score 1):

I made some silly connections in my circuit. It works now. Thank you, everyone. *The bottom one would not work in reality.

[image: Inverting]

[image: Noninverting]

Comment: Please, see my separate answer (comment to the 2nd graph).